# React unwanted refreshing after my post call to api

Tags: reactjs

I am confused as to why my react app is auto refreshing after I send a post call? On my server side I am using express and everything is saving to the database alright.  It should be retuning a res.status of 200 but before the code hits the .then() it auto refreshes.

here is my submit code:

```
onSubmit = (event) => {

  let body = {
    name: this.state.name,
    email: this.state.email,
    body : this.state.body,
    subject : this.state.subject,
  }

  fetch('/api/inbox', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
      debugger
    if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log("WORKED!!")
    //    this.setState({messageSent: true})
     
    } else {
      const error = new Error(res.error);
      throw error;
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    alert('Error logging in please try again');
  });
}
```

I put a debugger in but its never triggered. I don't want the screen to refresh since I want to show a success message after the result is returned.

Comment: Is `onSubmit` handler used for the `onSubmit` event handler on your form, like so `<form onSubmit={onSubmit} />`? If yes, you need to call `event.preventDefault()` inside the your handler, preferably on the first line.

Comment: There's no way to know given you haven't shown what triggers `onSubmit`. But if it's a form `onSubmit` as goto1 states, or if it's a `submit` button, then you need to prevent default browser handling of the submit event.